# Sqoop import table into Hive with Hive's Thrift server running or not

Tags: hadoop, hive, thrift, sqoop

I'm facing a problem importing table to Hive using sqoop.

In my java code, I SSH to the hive's server, and execute the sqoop import command, which import a table from postgresql to hive.

In my hive-site.xml, I specified:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
  <value>/hlservices/hive/warehouse</value>
  <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
</property>
```

If: Hive's thrift server not running:

The imported table will be `/hlservices/hive/warehouse/mytable` as hive-site.xml described.
I can also see the imported table in Hive's shell using "show tables" or "describe mytable"

Else if: Hive's thrift server running:

The imported table will be `/user/hlservices/mytable` (also a path in dfs), and I couldn't see it in Hive's shell.

Whether Thrift server is running or not will lead to different results!

It's painful for me to locate the file to change configuration due to unfamiliarity.

In my project, the thrift server need to be started and never stop. How can I tell sqoop or hive to pick up the correct path to do importing while hive's thrift is running?

All hive-site.xml files

```
./sqoop-1.4.4.bin__hadoop-1.0.0/testdata/hcatalog/conf/hive-site.xml
./hive-0.10.0/src/data/conf/hive-site.xml
./hive-0.10.0/src/common/src/test/resources/hive-site.xml
./hive-0.10.0/src/pdk/scripts/conf/hive-site.xml
./hive-0.10.0/src/conf/hive-site.xml
./hive-0.10.0/scripts/pdk/conf/hive-site.xml
./hive-0.10.0/conf/hive-site.xml
```

Among them, the first hive-site.xml in sqoop folder, has:

```
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
    <value>${test.build.data}/sqoop/warehouse</value>
  </property>
```

I tried to modify it and make it the same with hive-site.xml under hive's conf folder, but it didn't work

Comment: check your filesystem, are there different hive-site.xml with different `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` config?

Comment: I added new information in my post